# Disable window stretching Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

How do I disable the stretching of the window at the bottom right? I would have to deal with auto-sizing and all that stuff, which would be unnecessary if I simply didn't allow the user to stretch the window size.

Comment: Just set the maximum width/height to the minimum width/height?  Then you can't resize it at all.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Checking both the maximum and minimum size boxes. Thanks!!

Comment: @TwoDumpling: I'll just post it as an answer, then. ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First you should set the maximum width/height equal to the minimum width/height in IB:

[image]

Then you can disable the resize control by unchecking "Resize" in IB:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will never forget this, I've been looking for this for a while.

Answer (score 4):

Select the window in Interface Builder and uncheck the "Resize" checkbox in the Attributes Inspector panel